# Ionic, Cordova, Phonegap loading message

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova

I'm developing an app using the ionic framework with angular.js and I am finding my loading messages are disappearing before my content has loaded - here is some example code

```
$scope.validateUser = function () {
    var email = this.user.email;
    var password = this.user.password;
    if(!email || !password) {
        $rootScope.notify("Please enter valid credentials");
        return false;
    }
    $rootScope.show('Please wait.. Authenticating');
    API.signin({
        email: email,
        password: password
    }).success(function (data) {
        $rootScope.setToken(email); // create a session kind of thing on the client side
        $rootScope.hide();
        $window.location.href = ('#/database/list');
    }).error(function (error) {
        $rootScope.hide();
        $rootScope.notify("Invalid Username or password");
    });
}
```

The '#database/list' is grabbed from a RESTful API and the authenticating message vanishes before the page is rended in the app.

Am I right in thinking I should move the $rootScope.hide() to below the $window.location.href line, or is it something more sinister (i.e. I have warnings that $rootScope.hide() is depreciated and I should use $ionicLoading.hide();

I'm very new to Angular and app development (primarly PHP dev) so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try not to attach objects to the $rootScope, and instead use a service to store globally accessible data. Additionally you will want to look into how angular uses [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) to resolve remote data calls.

The basic idea is to call a function in your controller which in turn calls a login service to authenticate the user. 4 things happen once the call is made.

1. Display a loading screen
2. LoginService.login makes a remote call (via a promise) to authenticate the user
3. The controller waits until the LoginService.login promise is resolved
4. Once the promise resolves, the user object is updated with the received token and the loading screen is hidden.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/hannuraina/pen/srmLh)

The demo uses a timeout in place of an $http call to resolve the deferral.

View:

```
  <ion-content ng-controller="AppCtrl" has-header="true" padding="true">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="item">
        <button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
        <div ng-show="user.token">
          Logged in with token: {{user.token}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, LoginService) {
  $scope.user = {};

  $scope.login = function(usr, pwd) { 
    var result = LoginService.login(usr, pwd);

    // show loading screen
    $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Logging In...'});

    result.then(function(data) {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      $scope.user.token = data.token;
    });


    return result;
  }
});
```

LoginService:

```
.service('LoginService', function($q, $timeout) {
  return {
    login: function() {
      var defer = $q.defer();

      $timeout(function() {
         defer.resolve({token: new Date().getTime()});
      }, 3000);


      // replace timeout function with actual $http call
      // the $http call will return a promise equivelant to
      // defer.promise;
      //$http({
      //  url: '//myloginurl',
      //  params: {usr: 'myusr', pwd: 'mypwd'}
      //}).success(function(data) {
      //  // presume data contains json {token: some token}
      //  defer.resolve(data);
      //}).error(function(){
      //  defer.resolve();
      //});

      return defer.promise;
    }
  }  
});
```